# Using FileHelper library to parse CSV strings, but need to ignore newlines

Tags: c#, parsing, csv, filehelpers

I have read in some CSV values, line by line, that have the following format:

`30: "NY",  41: "JOHN S.",  36: "HAMPTON",  42: "123 Road Street, NY",  68: "Y"`

I need to break this down to something like the following in order to parse these items further:

`30: "NY"`

`41: "JOHN S."`

`36: "HAMPTON"`

`42: "123 Road Street, NY"` (note the comma)

`...`

I'm using the [FileHelper](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net) library, but it seems to like reading things in line-by-line, despite me wanting it split by it's delimited `,` commas.

I have the record class:

```cs
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
class BoxRecord
{
    public String record;
}
```

And I retrieve what I hoped would be several objects in an array via the following, but it just returns me the original line:

```cs
DelimitedFileEngine engine = new DelimitedFileEngine(typeof(BoxRecord));
BoxRecord[] boxes = (BoxRecord[])engine.ReadString(boxLine);
```

What I want `boxes[].record` to contain:

`30: "NY"`

`41: "JOHN S."`

`36: "HAMPTON"`

`42: "123 Road Street, NY"`

`...`

What it actually contains:

`30: "NY",  41: "JOHN S.",  36: "HAMPTON",  42: "123 Road Street, NY",  68: "Y"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the line, you can break the line based on below linq to get what you want:

```
string input = "30: \"NY\", 41: \"JOHN S.\", " +
   "36: \"HAMPTON\", 42: \"123 Road Street, NY\", 68: \"Y\"";

var tempList = input.Split('\"').ToList();

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, tempList.Count/2)
    .Select(i => string.Join(": "
        , tempList[2*i].Split(new[] { ',', ':' })
           .Single(ss => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ss))

        , tempList[2*i + 1]));
```

---

**Update:** Seem it's interesting for me, this code is to handle the case as your comment:

```
var tempList1 = input.Split(':').ToList();

var tempList2 = tempList1.SelectMany((s, index) =>
 {
     if (index == 0 || index == tempList1.Count - 1)
         return new List<string>() { s };

     var subList = s.Split(',');
     return new List<string>
           { 
                string.Concat(subList.Take(subList.Length - 1)),
                subList.Last()
           };
 }).ToList();

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, tempList2.Count / 2)
         .Select(i => string.Join(": ", tempList2[2 * i], tempList2[2 * i + 1]));
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks. Is there a way to edit this such that it would include an item like: `40: 12345`. Currently this works only for items that have quotes around them, e.g., `40: "12345"`

Comment: it's much appreciated. I hate to be the bearer of bad news, doesn't work for the line (truncates the rest of the value after the `AVE,` comma):
`String test = "20: \"STEVE\",  12: \"JONES\",  96: \"1600 PENNSYLVANIA AVE, NW\"";`

Answer (score 1):

The sample you're looking at is not, technically speaking, a valid CSV format file.  Basically, whomever provided the file used the text qualifier symbol - the double quote " - in a non-standard way.  The traditional way to use it is this:

```
123,"Sue said, ""Hi, this is a test!""",2012-08-15
```

This statement should parse as this:

```
Assert.AreEqual(line.Length, 3);
Assert.AreEqual(line[0], @"123");
Assert.AreEqual(line[1], @"Sue said, ""Hi, this is a test!""");
Assert.AreEqual(line[2], @"2012-08-15");
```

From the sample CSV provided in your question, according to the standards I've seen, the correct processing should basically treat the quote marks as regular characters within the string rather than text qualifiers.  Here's how I interpret your line - please do let me know if I'm wrong, though!

```
Assert.AreEqual(line.Length, 6);
Assert.AreEqual(line[0], @"30: ""NY""");
Assert.AreEqual(line[1], @" 41: ""JOHN S.""");
Assert.AreEqual(line[2], @" 36: ""HAMPTON""");
Assert.AreEqual(line[3], @" 42: ""123 Road Street");
Assert.AreEqual(line[4], @" NY""");
Assert.AreEqual(line[5], @" 68: ""Y""");
```

I would imagine FileHelper is breaking because it can't determine if the text is either text qualified or properly delimited.  You'd definitely be best off using custom code to handle this one; the solution provided by Cuong Le seems good for your solution.

For reference, my C# CSV library is here: https://code.google.com/p/csharp-csv-reader/

EDIT: For fun's sake, I wondered if it would be possible to decode this using a regular expression.  Your data is consistently formatted, even if it's not strictly CSV, so perhaps this is something else for your toolbox:

```
String mystring = @"30: ""NY"", 41: ""JOHN S."", 36: ""HAMPTON"", 42: ""123 Road Street, NY"", 68: ""Y""
    20: ""STEVE"", 12: ""JONES"", 96: ""1600 PENNSYLVANIA AVE, NW""
    30: ""NY"", 41: ""JOHN S."", 36: ""HAMPTON"", 42: ""123 Road Street, NY"", 68: ""Y"", 40: 12345";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<id>\d*): (""(?<field>[^""]*)""|(?<field>[\d]*))");
MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(mystring);
foreach (Match m in mc) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", m.Groups["id"], m.Groups["field"]);
}
```

Basically, the regex works by looking for two decimal digits, followed by a colon - space - doublequote.  It then finds all text until it reaches another doublequote.  From my testing, this also produces correct matches for both of the test lines you've described in your question.

If my regex isn't quite correct, there's a nifty online regex tester available here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ - Try copying and pasting your data into the search area, and then use this  regex string as a starting point:

```
(?<id>\d*): ("(?<field>[^"]*)"|(?<field>[\d]*))
```

EDIT2: I fixed the Regex to also take into account the "40: 12345" value you cited in your comment below.  It now detects all fields correctly on all of the examples.

EDIT3: From another request, this regex now supports unlimited length numbers before the colon.  Here's a quick explanation of how the regex works:

- `(?<id>\d*)` - This first chunk is called a capturing group - a capturing group is surrounded by parenthesis.  It attempts to capture a repeating string (`*`) of decimal digits (`\d`) and give it the name "id" (`?<id>`).
- `:` - Matches the colon space in between records.
- `"(?<field>[^"]*)"` - finds a beginning quotation mark, then a large number of characters other than a quotation mark (`[^"]`), ending with another quotation mark.  Saves the result in "field".
- `(?<field>[\d]*)` - Finds any number of decimal digits and saves the result in "field".  Note that some regex engines don't support having two capture groups with the same name; you may have to call one "field1" and the other "field2".

Comment: Thanks Ted. You're entirely correct -- the whole point of this project is to see if we can do anything useful with this completely non-standard data. I wrote my own parser which works, but I'll be going back to Cuong Le's answer because he is more awesome than I am.

Comment: Glad to hear you've got this one solved!  I'm always on the lookout for weird CSV edge cases, so thank you for sharing this one.

Comment: I tried your regex for fun. It's awesome. The first one to work! ... almost - it only takes 2 character line numbers. E.g., `100: "SPENCE"` outputs as `00: SPENCE`

Comment: Oh - that's an easy fix.  Here's a modified REGEX that handles unlimited characters.  (?<id>\d*): ("(?<field1>[^"]*)"|(?<field2>[\d]*))

Comment: The sample he provided is valid, since it has no embedded double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Despite all the "Don't re-invent the wheel" posts I've come across (all of them), it's the best solution for me and the only one I've found to work.

I've tried using the FileHelper framework, Cuong Le's answer, and VB `TextFieldParser`. Each worked and didn't work in different ways.

I needed to be able to parse this (a "non-standard" CSV format). These lines are inputs from a file, but not a CSV file. They are part of a larger structure:

`30: "NY", 41: "JOHN S.", 36: "HAMPTON", 42: "123 Road Street, NY", 68: "Y", 40: 12345`

---

FileHelper would split on commas in quotes, e.g,:

`123 Road Street, NY`

becomes

`213 Road Street`

`NY`

Cuong Le's answer didn't handle the case: `40: 12345` (the data value without quotes)

TextFieldParser would also split on commas in quotes, like FileHelper.

---

My quick-n-dirty, roll-your-own solution (and it works!):

```cs
    private List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> SplitBoxLine(String input)
    {
        //SAMPLE input:
        //30: "NY", 41: "JOHN S.", 36: "HAMPTON", 42: "123 Road Street, NY", 68: "Y", 40: 12345

        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> boxes = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        int quoteCount = 0;
        String buffer = "";
        String boxNum = "";
        String boxValue = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == input.Length - 1)
            {
                //if the input character at the end ISN'T a quote or comma, add it to the buffer
                //supports the case where the last item is 40: 12345
                if (input[i] != ',' && input[i] != '\"')
                {
                    buffer += input[i];
                }
                boxValue = String.Copy(buffer.Trim());

                //once we have the value, we can create the pair
                KeyValuePair<string, string> pair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(boxNum, boxValue);
                boxes.Add(pair);

                Console.WriteLine("BOX VALUE [LAST ITEM]: " + boxValue);
            }

            if (input[i] == ':')
            {
                boxNum = String.Copy(buffer.Trim());
                buffer = "";
                Console.WriteLine("BOX NUM: " + boxNum);
            }
            else if (input[i] == '\"')
            {
                quoteCount++;
            }
            else if (input[i] == ',')
            {
                if (quoteCount % 2 == 0) //comma occurs outside of quotes
                {
                    boxValue = String.Copy(buffer.Trim());
                    buffer = "";

                    //once we have the value, we can create the pair
                    KeyValuePair<string, string> pair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(boxNum, boxValue);
                    boxes.Add(pair);

                    Console.WriteLine("BOX VALUE: " + boxValue);
                }
                else //the comma occurs in some quotes
                {
                    buffer += input[i]; //add the comma, it's just part of the boxValue
                }
            }
            //nothing special about this chacter, add it to the buffer and continue
            else
            {
                buffer += input[i];
            }
        }

        return boxes;
    }
```